# Does Blueprint CSS use some standard dimensions?

Tags: css, sass, blueprint-css

I wonder how Blueprint CSS work -- does it use some standard dimensions (such as 24 columns with 40 pixel width, or 20 columns with 48 pixel width), and is there usually a file that specifies the specifics of the blueprint settings?

Answer (score 3):

The official [quick start tutorial](http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/wiki/Quick-Start-Tutorial) details out the dimensions as:

> By default, the grid is 950px wide, with 24 columns spanning 30px, and a 10px margin between columns.

There's also [BlueCalc](http://bluecalc.xily.info/) which allows you to generate your own grid.css file with specific column widths, gutters, etc.

The column widths are can also be modified manually by modifying the grid.css file in the BlueprintCSS package.  The span-1 to span-24 classes each have an absolute width set (though using BlueCalc is a bit easier to visually see the changes you are making).